# Symfony2 inherit from two form templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I've set my forms to use a custom template (that produces a DL) and that works fine

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'myBundle:Form:row.html.twig'
```

But then I want to customise one row of one form and I think I have to do this

```
{% form_theme edit_form _self, ' %}

{% block _startYear_row %}
    {% block form_row %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <div id="startCalendaryear"></div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

That make the entire form inherit from _self and loses the customisation of row.html.twig.

How can I set a custom template for all forms while still overriding a single row on one of them?

Comment: I actually don't know if this will work: Create a new template which inherit `myBundle:Form:row.html.twig` and contains the custom template. Now you set that file as `form_theme`.